# Can we have better 'projects' support in the CV section of careers?

Tags: feature-request, jobs, cv

The projects section is just a simple block of rich text.  It would be nice for people who participate in multiple projects to be able to provide a specific section for each, including tags and your own role in the project.  Basically a duplication of the experience section but with the implicit indication that this is not employment information but voluntary participation in other areas.

Alternatively, it could be made clearer that the 'experience' section does not have to be tied to an employer as opposed to a open source project.

Comment: This would be perfect.  I have a small business on the side doing freelance projects.  Many of these have been sites I archetected and developed gaining skills that I don't use in my fulltime job.  It would be cool to be able to tag these projects too.

Comment: I ran into this problem too. This would be very usefull.

Answer (score 1):

I agree. I work on a lot of projects on my own time in order to learn new technologies, and I'd really like to be able to tag them on an individual basis and show that I have experience with them, even if it doesn't pertain to my work history.