# Let us list Technologies for projects in CVs

Tags: feature-request, jobs, technology, project

[Related Suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31891/can-we-have-better-projects-support-in-the-cv-section-of-careers)

I think the Projects and Links section should be broken into two (Projects becoming separate) and have the projects section behave similarly to education or employment.

I'm thinking:

1. Name
2. Link (optional)
3. Technologies (tags)
4. Description/Role

The important part is breaking the Technologies list out of plain-text (the rest is just formatting, which I care much less about).  Currently, you're limited to 10 "outside of employment/education" technology tags.  If you do alot of hobbyist stuff (open source work being the elephant in the room) or your education had lots of diverse projects you're going to run out.

What prompted idea this was [Jeff's recent dogfooding](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/eating-our-own-careers-dogfood/) post; I went to see if my CV could be expected to show up in a search, based on the content of the post.  The biggest flaw that I saw was that although I have experience with most of the technologies mentioned, due to the scarcity of tags/technologies a number of them only appear in the Projects and Links section.